Не работает бот на пайтон
Когда пытаюсь реализовать сценарий разговора через Conversation Handler и запуская команду /new , то выдаёт это:
File "C:\Users\Мурзик\Downloads\tg_bot_2_0.py", line 85, in new
await update.message.reply_text(f"Вводите ваши данные \n", "Вопрос 1: Ваше имя:")
File "C:\Users\Мурзик\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\site-packages\telegram_message.py", line 1771, in reply_text
return await self.get_bot().send_message(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...<20 lines>...
)
^
File "C:\Users\Мурзик\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\site-packages\telegram\ext_extbot.py", line 2928, in send_message
return await super().send_message(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...<21 lines>...
)
^
File "C:\Users\Мурзик\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\site-packages\telegram_bot.py", line 1017, in send_message
return await self._send_message(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...<19 lines>...
)
^
File "C:\Users\Мурзик\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\site-packages\telegram\ext_extbot.py", line 607, in _send_message
result = await super()._send_message(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...<21 lines>...
)
^
File "C:\Users\Мурзик\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\site-packages\telegram_bot.py", line 729, in _send_message
result = await self._post(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...<7 lines>...
)
^
File "C:\Users\Мурзик\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\site-packages\telegram_bot.py", line 617, in _post
return await self._do_post(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...<6 lines>...
)
^
File "C:\Users\Мурзик\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\site-packages\telegram\ext_extbot.py", line 351, in _do_post
return await super()._do_post(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...<6 lines>...
)
^
File "C:\Users\Мурзик\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\site-packages\telegram_bot.py", line 646, in _do_post
result = await request.post(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...<6 lines>...
)
^
File "C:\Users\Мурзик\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\site-packages\telegram\request_baserequest.py", line 202, in post
result = await self._request_wrapper(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...<7 lines>...
Что делать?
Ниже приложена функция /new
    """Отправляет сообщение когда получена команда /new"""
    await update.message.reply_text(f"Вводите ваши данные \n", "Вопрос 1: Ваше имя:")

    return 1```


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. попробуйте начать с формулировки заголовка вопроса.

Откройте документацию метода reply_text и там прочитайте, какой тип должен быть у второго аргумента
